# How to deal with character going under parts of map?

Tags: render, game-physics

In all of my projects I have been rendering the whole map and then all entities. But now there are parts, where entities have to go under some parts of the map, and I am just sitting here no idea how to do it.

My (pseudocode) renderer:

```
Render(){

  For all Layers
    For all Rows
      For all Blocks
        Block.Render()


  For all Entities
    Entity.Render();

}
```

Which ends in entities overdrawing over parts of the map they are supposed to be under. How to theoretically do it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on your particular rendering scheme, but assuming top down view, something along these lines:

```
Render(){
  For all Layers from bottom to top
    For all Rows in layer
      For all Blocks in row
        Block.Render()
    For all Entities on layer
      Entity.Render()
}
```

I.e. render things descending-ordered by distance from the camera, which corresponds to layer number.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by yuri kilochek in his answer, you can indeed use the [painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter's_algorithm) here.

Another way of handling this could be, depending on what your `Block` and `Entity` classes look like, to have all of them in an array, and then `sort` this array to get back a similar structure as before. The main drawbacks I can see here might be that the sort can be expensive (depending on how much items you want to render), and that you might need your objects to know their row / layer to be able to sort them.

You could also take profit of [the z-buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering) if you are using *opengl* or *directx* to render your scene. The idea would be to enrich your vertices data with the `layer` each object is, and then let the `z-buffer` magic happen by enabling objects with a `greater or equal` layer value to be drawn. This would allow you to keep your actual render loop while taking into account the layers your objects are in.